# How can I insert a counter to count the number of loans a customer has had in r

Tags: r

Have a data set of borrowers who have had multiple loans. I would like to insert a loan counter that counts each loan. Below is table in which I show how I would like the counter to look. I would also create a new column that shows the maximum number of loans a borrower has ever had. I would also like to insert two new columns. One which identifies the first loan for each borrower and the other which identifies the last loan for each borrower. Please see the table below[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example:) In that way, others are more likely to provide you with a suiting answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your loans are in order (e.g., by `Loan_Date`), you can take this approach using `tidyverse`. Use `group_by` to evaluate the loans for a given `Customer_ID`, and then use `row_number` and `n()` to determine the column values desired.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Customer_ID) %>%
  mutate(LoanCounter = row_number(),
         MaxLoan = n(),
         FirstLoan = ifelse(row_number() == 1, 1, 0),
         LastLoan = ifelse(row_number() == n(), 1, 0))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   Customer_ID [2]
  Customer_ID Customer_Account Loan_Date LoanCounter MaxLoan FirstLoan LastLoan
        <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>       <int>   <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1      100100             1001    200801           1       5         1        0
2      100100             1002    200902           2       5         0        0
3      100100             1003    201003           3       5         0        0
4      100100             1004    201105           4       5         0        0
5      100100             1005    201209           5       5         0        1
6      100102             2001    201805           1       4         1        0
7      100102             2006    201903           2       4         0        0
8      100102             2010    201905           3       4         0        0
9      100102              238    202002           4       4         0        1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Customer_ID = c(100100, 100100, 100100, 100100, 
100100, 100102, 100102, 100102, 100102), Customer_Account = c(1001, 
1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 2001, 2006, 2010, 238), Loan_Date = c(200801, 
200902, 201003, 201105, 201209, 201805, 201903, 201905, 202002
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```